# ```pipdeptree --reverse --packages xgboost``` - how to resovle library incompatibility

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, xgboost, kaggle

**GOAL**

- My final goal would be to run this [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/vinhnguyen/accelerating-xgboost-with-gpu) project locally in a conda environment.
- I am running this on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, conda environment, python 3.8

**INPUT**

- I have got recommended to run [this](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3225#issuecomment-383059286) code because I have library dependencies issues.

```
pipdeptree --reverse --packages xgboost
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Warning!!! Possibly conflicting dependencies found:
* wandb==0.10.4
 - subprocess32 [required: >=3.5.3, installed: ?]
* spyder==4.1.5
 - pyqt5 [required: <5.13, installed: ?]
 - pyqtwebengine [required: <5.13, installed: ?]
* QDarkStyle==2.8.1
 - helpdev [required: >=0.6.10, installed: ?]
* Flask-Compress==1.5.0
 - brotli [required: Any, installed: ?]
* dask-xgboost==0.1.11
 - xgboost [required: <=0.90, installed: 1.2.0]
* dash==1.16.3
 - dash-core-components [required: ==1.12.1, installed: 1.3.1]
 - dash-html-components [required: ==1.1.1, installed: 1.0.1]
 - dash-renderer [required: ==1.8.2, installed: 1.1.2]
 - dash-table [required: ==4.10.1, installed: 4.4.1]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
xgboost==1.2.0
  - dask-xgboost==0.1.11 [requires: xgboost<=0.90]
```

**UPDATE**

Now I have reinstalled XGBoost and

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

when I run my code's import in jupyter it says

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f5a95d2c9926> in <module>
      3 from dask.distributed import Client
      4 from dask import array as da
----> 5 import xgboost as xgb
      6 from xgboost import dask as dxgb
      7 from xgboost.dask import DaskDMatrix

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new conda environment do you get the same error? E.g.

```
conda create -n kaggle_xgboost_test python=3.8 pandas numpy scikit-learn xgboost jupyter
conda activate kaggle_xgboost_test

# Then open a notebook
jupyter-notebook

# And try to import xgboost with e.g.
import xgboost
print("imported ok")
```

### Edit

If the fresh environment installed/imported xgboost without any issues (as your comment suggests), then the problem you're having is unique to your existing environment. Have you resolved the conflicts identified by `pipdeptree --reverse --packages xgboost`? Have you tried [building xgboost from source with GPU support enabled](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#id11)? E.g.

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON
make -j4
```

Comment: In other environments it is not a problem but the issue is that I have reinstalled xgboost here if I call ```conda list``` than xgboost ist ehre and py-xgboost is as well but the import says it tis not there. (I have checked I am viewing the correct environment with the correct notebook url). the goal would be as it is in the kaggle project to get xgboost that supports to run on GPU (Nvidia)